# Questions on different quotes

Tags: java, android, xml, quotes, symbols

I am having some problem with xml parsing in java. The quote found in a text is like this in different browser text encoding:

```
iso-8859-1 | utf-8
(â€œ | “
â€   | ”
â€™  | ’
```

I tried to parse both in xml string to display in my android app. However, neither of the symbols are able to parse successfully.

I am forced to replace “ to " and ’ to ' ( and encode them in php 
) before the text can be parsed.

May I know why is it? The XML parser doesn't allow any special symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Most XML parsers should enable you to specify the encoding your input is in. If you're using the XMLPullParser, you can change it like this:

```
parser.setInput(this.getInputStream(),"UTF-8");
```

If you're using SAX with an InputStream, change the encoding of the InputStream like this:

```
is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: I tried the setInput UTF-8, here is the warning for special double quotes:
W/System.err(341): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unresolved: &acirc;

Comment: I found out the xml string generated in php from mysql db, the double quotes become &acirc;��. How do I fix it in the first place?

Comment: And I tried manual input special quote in xml string. However when parse in android, the quote still become some symbols â€

Comment: The XML comes from a PHP script, I understand. What `content-type` does it specify when sending the reply?